# Slice order guarantee based on order of insertion

Tags: go, slice

This is super trivial question but I could not find it asked here. Sorry if I missed it.

Can I count that the order in slice is always the order of insertion of elements in that slice?
I tested it with the following code:

```
func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        testOrder()
    }
}

func testOrder() {
    sl := []int{}
    for i := 0; i < 50; i++ {
        sl = append(sl, i)
    }
    for i, el := range sl {
        if el != i {
            panic("Order not quaranteed")
        }
    }
}
```

Fill a slice with numbers and then check if the order of elements in the slice is as they were populated in it. I do this check 10000 times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not inserting but appending. [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) always appends the elements to the end of the slice, and it does not leave "holes". So yes, you can count on that your example will never panic with `"Order not guaranteed"`.

Read more about the `append()` function in its doc: https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append

Also in the [Spec: Appending to and copying slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)

Also read official blog post: [The Go Blog: Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](https://blog.golang.org/slices)

Answer (score 2):

Slices and arrays are sequentially ordered structures. The order of elements will never change if you append to them, even if they are copied in memory.